# Poping different viewcontroller using poptoviewcontroller

Tags: objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, pushviewcontroller, poptoviewcontroller

I have an application that contain three `viewcontrollers`

`Mapview` is `rootviewcontroller`

mapview -pushviewcontroller -  listview,

listview - pushviewcontroller - mapview,

1st conditon

mapview -pushviewcontroller -  cityview and 
cityview - pushviewcontroller  - mapview

2nd conditon

listview -pushviewcontroller -  cityview and
cityview - pushviewcontroller - listview

order of viewcontroller like this

mapview-listview,
mapview-cityview,
listview-cityview

the problem is i am using `[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];`
but it works only on 1st condition not for 2nd condition
when i use this in the 2nd condition it show mapview again

ie. listview pushing successfully to the cityview and i want to pop back to the listview but it back again to the mapview not to the listview

even i also try this 
`[self popToViewControllerAtIndex:1 animated:YES];`

but again it shows the same problem.

I have tried pretty much everything I have found in forums.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

To modify (pop views) navigation stack you can use next methods:

1. *Replaces the view controllers currently managed by the navigation controller with the specified items.*

   `- (void)setViewControllers:(NSArray *)viewControllers animated:(BOOL)animated`
2. *Pops the top view controller from the navigation stack and updates the display.*

   `- (UIViewController *)popViewControllerAnimated:(BOOL)animated`
3. *Pops all the view controllers on the stack except the root view controller and updates the display.*

   `- (NSArray *)popToRootViewControllerAnimated:(BOOL)animated`
4. *Pops view controllers until the specified view controller is at the top of the navigation stack.*

   `- (NSArray *)popToViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated`

To access current view controllers on the stack you can use `@property(nonatomic, copy) NSArray *viewControllers`